# Tomcat Migration - Authentication Issue

Tags: java, forms-authentication, tomcat7

I am trying to migrate to Tomcat 7 from Tomcat 6.

The app uses form authentication and when logging in the app gets stuck at /j_security_check as a blank white page.

Tomcat is displaying the user is authenticated and an error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.catalina.realm.GenericPrincipal.getRealm()Lorg/apache/catalina/Realm;
```

Not sure where to go from here.

[EDIT]

the server.xml file on the tomcat server is just the default.

context.xml in the application

```
  <Realm 
    appName="Informer" className="AuthRealm" 
    dbContext="java:comp/env/jdbc/appdb" debug="2" 
    krbFile="C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache Tomcat 7.0.14\\conf\\krb5.conf"
    loginFile="C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache Tomcat 7.0.14\\conf\\jaas.conf"                     
    ndcLdap="ldap://server:389" 
    nedLdap="ldap://server:389" roleClassNames="" 
    useContextClassLoader="true" userClassNames="" />
```

[[ EDIT ]]

I am calling the getRealm() method to generate a new GenericPrincipal object.  Looks like I just need to update to the new constructor.

[[[ EDIT ]]]

Two issues.  I was calling getRealm() and the call was in a constructor that did not take the realm as a parameter anymore.

So I looked up the new constructor for GenericPrincipal and all I had to do was remove the getRealm() call from the parameters.

Resolved.

Regards,

Comment: What's in your configuration files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that **`AuthRealm`** class in the Tomcat docs. I guess it's a custom `Realm` which was programmed against Tomcat 6 and now the API has changed.

The object `org.apache.catalina.realm.GenericPrincipal` changed from [version 6](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/tomcat/tomcat-6.0.32/org/apache/catalina/realm/GenericPrincipal.java.html) to [version 7](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/tomcat/tomcat-7.0.19/org/apache/catalina/realm/GenericPrincipal.java.html) and now it doesn't have the `getRealm()` method.

Comment: just had to update the constructor by removing the getRealm() call